# can't get my defaultAuto state to filter like my defaultData state

Tags: reactjs, json, redux, filter

React/ redux - I have two JSON files loaded into my store. I'm trying to have an autocomplete div drop below search bar that is tied to an id. That id will give me a search word that I can fire off using a function to complete the search query `queryAutoComplete()`. For some weird reason, by `querySuggestion` in `<SearchBar />` isn't working the same way using `defaultAuto` as using `defaultData` and I am not understanding why. I console log them and I see the objects. I keep getting the error that includes isn't a function with my array...

```js
//ConfigureStore
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Reducer, initialState } from './reducer';

export const ConfigureStore = () => {
    const store = createStore(
        Reducer, 
        initialState
    )

    return store
    
    

//Reducers
import Data from '../Shared/data.json'
import Suggestion from '../Shared/suggestions.json'

export const initialState = {
    data: Data,
    suggestion: Suggestion
}

export const Reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    return state
}




//App.js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Main from "./Components/Main"
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { ConfigureStore } from './redux/configureStore'

const store = ConfigureStore()

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Main />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import RenderGrid from './RenderGrid'
import SearchBar from './SearchBar'
import { Header } from "./Header";
import { Footer } from "./Footer";


const Main = () => {
    const [defaultAuto, setDefaultAuto] = useState()
    const [defaultData, setDefaultData] = useState()

    const [search, setSearch] = useState("")
    const [results, setResults] = useState([])
    const [sugg, setSugg] = useState([])
    
    const data = useSelector(state => state.data)
    const suggestion = useSelector(state => state.suggestion)
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const createData = () => {
            setDefaultData(data)
            setDefaultAuto(suggestion)
        }
        return createData()
    }, [data, suggestion])  
   
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <SearchBar 
            placeholder="What do you identify as?" 
            defaultData={defaultData} //JSON data for Grid
            defaultAuto={defaultAuto} // JSON data for auto-complete box
            search={search} 
            setSearch={setSearch} 
            setResults={setResults} 
            sugg={sugg} 
            setSugg={setSugg} />
            <RenderGrid results={results} />                
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
    
    
}
export default Main
```

```js
import React from "react";
import Suggestion from "./Suggestion";
import { BiSearchAlt } from "react-icons/bi";
import { RiCloseCircleLine } from "react-icons/ri";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const SearchBar = ({
  placeholder,
  search,
  setResults,
  setSearch,
  defaultData,
  sugg,
  setSugg,
  defaultAuto
  }) => {
    const querySuggestion = (e) => {
      setSearch(e.target.value)
      console.log(defaultAuto)
      const filteredSuggg = defaultAuto.filter((auto) => {
        return (
        auto.eth.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
        auto.gen.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
        auto.iden.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
        )
        })
        setSugg(filteredSuggg)
        console.log(sugg)
    };
// query logic for enter key and suggestion click
    const queryAutoComplete = (e) => {
      const filteredSearch = defaultData.filter((data) => {
        return (
          data.eth.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
          data.gen.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
          data.iden.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
        )
      })
      setResults(filteredSearch)
      setSugg([])
    };

    const queryJson = (e) => {
      if (e.key === "Enter") {
        const filteredSearch = defaultData.filter((data) => {
          return (
            data.eth.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
            data.gen.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
            data.iden.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
          );
        });
        setResults(filteredSearch);
      }
    };

    const clearInput = () => {
      setResults([])
      setSearch("")
      setSugg([])
    };

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="search-input">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder={placeholder}
            value={search}
            onChange={querySuggestion}
            onKeyPress={queryJson}
          />
          <Suggestion 
          search={search} 
          sugg={sugg} 
          setSugg={setSugg} 
          queryAutoComplete={queryAutoComplete} 
          />

          <div className="searchIcon">
            {search.length > 0 ? (
              <RiCloseCircleLine
                icon="fa-solid fa-times-circle"
                className="icon"
                onClick={clearInput}
              />
            ) : (
              <BiSearchAlt icon="fa-solid fa-search" className="icon" />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
};
export default SearchBar;
```

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const Suggestion = ({ search, sugg, queryAutoComplete }) => {


  
  const suggestionArray = sugg.map((arr) => (
      <div key={arr.id} onClick={() => queryAutoComplete()}>
        <li className="col-12">{arr.gen||arr.iden||arr.eth}</li>
      </div>
    ))

  useEffect(() => {
    const querySugg = () => {
      if (search.length > 0) {
        console.log("QuerySugg fired!!")
        console.log(search)
      }
    };
    querySugg()
  }, [search])
  console.log(sugg)
  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {suggestionArray}
    </div>
  )
}
export default Suggestion
```

```js
// data.json
[
  {
    "id": "61b3af7514270baddf9f5487",
    "eth": "Guatemalan",
    "gen": "male",
    "iden": "gay",
    "title": "Officia incididunt.",
    "about": "Incididunt cupidatat irure deserunt in et.",
    "img": "../public/img/test_img.jpg",
    "char": 3,
    "set": "Eden",
    "firstN": "Shauna",
    "lastN": "Greer",
    "email": "amet@gmail.com",
    "bio": "Irure consectetur voluptate in sint. Fugiat fugiat dolore esse occaecat pariatur amet. Dolor Lorem deserunt in. Esse adipisicing occaecat mollit magna amet aute amet. Elit est sint nostrud ad exercitation aute. Ut aliquip excepteur do dolor irure. Magna dolore laborum consectetur commodo veniam eiusmod veniam."
  },
  {
    "id": "61b3af75e6902e7ad64f378b",
    "eth": "Cuban",
    "gen": "trans",
    "iden": "lesbian",
    "title": "Non sint dolor ad fugiat nisi.",
    "about": "Fugiat culpa ullamco adipisicing labore voluptate.",
    "img": "../public/img/test_img.jpg",
    "char": 3,
    "set": "Accoville",
    "firstN": "Annmarie",
    "lastN": "Frye",
    "email": "veniam@gmail.com",
    "bio": "Excepteur sint nulla mollit laboris esse consequat. Reprehenderit amet amet commodo mollit anim duis anim. Nulla proident dolore ipsum Lorem anim. Ut aute Lorem tempor. Cupidatat minim duis labore fugiat consequat. Dolore ea velit et ut incididunt occaecat duis. Ad Lorem dolore excepteur esse elit."
  }, //etc total: 100 objects

//submissions.js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "eth": "puerto rican"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "eth": "mexican"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "eth": "dominican"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "eth": "cuban"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "eth": "chilean"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "eth": "brazilian"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "eth": "salvadoran"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "eth": "guatemalan"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "eth": "colombian"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "gen": "male"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "gen": "female"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "gen": "non-binary"
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "gen": "trans"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "iden": "straight"
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "iden": "bi"
    },
    {
        "id": 16,
        "iden": "gay"
    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "iden": "lesbian"
    }
    
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `defaultAuto` contains eather `eth`, `gen` or `iden`.
So you need to change a bit the `querySuggestion` function:

```
const querySuggestion = e => {
  setSearch(e.target.value);
  console.log(defaultAuto);
  const filteredSuggg = defaultAuto.filter(auto => {
    return (
      (auto.eth ||auto.gen || auto.iden).toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    );
  });
  setSugg(filteredSuggg);
  console.log(sugg);
};
```